# How do I display a single JSON object in the template

Tags: json, http, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a detail component that is supposed to display the 5 day forecast for a given city and I am able to retrieve the data successfully when I call the http.get(Url) method.

However I'm not sure how to bind this JSON data to my view.

*I know how to display data in a list view but I'm not sure how to display a single object.

**Detail Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-detail',
  templateUrl: './weather-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-detail.component.css']
})
export class WeatherDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public weatherDetailItem: any;
  private name: any;

  constructor(
    private weatherService: WeatherService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ){}

  //This method will retrieve the 5 day forecast for the city name in the route param
  getWeatherItem(){
    this.weatherService.fetchDetail(this.name)
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.weatherDetailItem = data;
      })
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    this.getWeatherItem();
  }


}
```

**fetchDetail()** calls the http.get method and grabs me this data:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Dallas&units=imperial&appid=f630449a4407b742703bf37d8e8c9057

In my template I have this:

```
<div>
   <h3>CITY:</h3>
   <h3>{{weatherDetailItem}}</h3>
</div>
```

When I actually load the page, it gives me  ***City: [object Object]***. I tried to access that JSON data with ***{{weatherDetailItem.city.name}}*** but received an error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: how did you get `City:[Object Object]`? If its true, then it should be `weatherDetailItem?.city[0].name`.

Comment: I think it's because I did `subscribe((data) => {this.weatherDetailItem = data;})` then displayed it using `{{weatherDetailItem}}` which is probably displaying the data object itself and not the data inside. If I call `{{weatherDetailItem.city.name}}` I get an error that says "Cannot read property 'city' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `?.` operator (for async call). So,
It should be

#### {{weatherDetailItem?.city.name}}

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.weatherDetailItem = data.city.name
```

Can you set the detail here? The issue is because the data is loading asynchronously, and at the time of the render, doesn't exists.

Comment: Oh ok, I just changed my getWeatherItem() method to:

`this.weatherService.fetchDetail(this.name).subscribe((data) => {this.weatherDetailItem = data.city.name;})`

 that allows me to display the city name now when I call `{{weatherDetailItem}}` in my template. How would I bind the rest of the data to my weatherDetailItem? For example, if I wanted to call `{{weatherDetailItem.city.name}}` and `{{weatherDetailItem.list[0].main.temp}}`